# changing the root directory name (not public) of Laravel Installation

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, rename

I have installed laravel 5.2 with the folder name "MyProject" and i have created controllers, views and models completely.

Now i access this project on localhost as say `http://localhost/MyProject/admin` etc..

Now instead of MyProject i want my project name so I changed root directory "Apisetproj" and everything is working fine and I am accessing project like `http://localhost/Apisetproj/admin`

though everything seems to be working fine, but i want to make sure from the experts that there is not any settings/configuration needed when root directory name is changed. Because this should not create any problem in future .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use

```
php artisan app:name
```

---

### [Naming Your Application](https://laravel.com/docs/5.0/configuration#after-installation)

> After installing Laravel, you may wish to "name" your application. By default, the app directory is namespaced under App, and autoloaded by Composer using the PSR-4 autoloading standard. However, you may change the namespace to match the name of your application, which you can easily do via the app:name Artisan command.

For example, if your application is named "Horsefly", you could run the following command from the root of your installation:

```
php artisan app:name Horsefly
```

> **Renaming your application is entirely optional**, and you are free to keep the App namespace if you wish